# ¿Como insertar en un ArrayList numeros aleatorios, mediante un bucle for-each en java?

Tags: java

> Este es mi intento por hacerlo pero me sale  esto :
>   [image: Este es mi resultado, que deberia salir otro numero pero sale este.]**Hago primero un método aleatorio para un dado y despues quiero meter esos aleatorios en el ArrayList, pero algo sale mal, y me imprime la suma en cero**

```
import java.util.*;
public class prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lista.ensureCapacity(7);

        for(int i : lista){
            lista.add(aleat());
            }
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : lista)
            sum =sum+lista.get(i);
        System.out.println("Longitud total = " + sum);
        //System.out.print(lista.get(0));
    }
    public static int aleat(){
        return (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas definiendo una lista sin elementos, aunque aseguras su capacidad mediante `lista.ensureCapacity(7)`, pero esto no determina el tamaño de la lista, por lo tanto nunca agregara elementos, ya que en este punto `lista` contiene 0 elementos:

```
    for(int i : lista){
        lista.add(aleat());
     }
```

Cambia el for , definiendo la cantidad de elementos a agregar, por ejemplo 7 (que son los elementos que obtiene tu método `aleat()` ):

```
 for(int i =0; i < 7; i++){
    lista.add(aleat());
 }
```

---

Este sería el código correcto:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   // lista.ensureCapacity(2);

    //for(int i : lista){
     for(int i =0; i < 8; i++){
        lista.add(aleat());
        }
    int sum = 0;      

    for (int i : lista){
        //sum =sum+lista.get(i);
        sum =sum+i;
    }
    System.out.println("Longitud total = " + sum);
```

Comment: vamo a ver  si sale

Comment: gracias si sale , pero porque nunca va agregar elementos??

Comment: de todas formas gracias, creo que es porque cuando pongo lo que yo puse entonces no queda definido el numero de elementos que va a ver, sino solo la capacidad//creo.

Comment: @matt a que te refieres con que nunca agrega elementos, comentame detalles y te ayudo.

Comment: @matt por cierto tienes un error en la suma, al realizar el for y obtener el elemento de la lista en la variable "i", ese es el valor que debes sumar, saludos!

Comment: gracias Elenasys.